# Which branch of mathematics deals with errors?

Tags: arithmetic

Maths is a concrete language which is definite in terms of it's accuracy. But, it seems mathematics also has it's flaws. Consider an example such as:[image]

seeing this we can only say that the whole process is incorrect. Hence, it is a mathematical flaw. I'd like to know if there is a branch of mathematics which deals with these specifics.

Comment: There's no flaw: you didn't apply the rules of simplification in a correct way. You can only simplify a factor which is non zero.

Comment: Every branch of mathematics deals with errors... and tries to eliminate them.  Yours is an elementary error based on the undefined term $0/0$.

Comment: it's just an example, there are infinite number of problems that also doesn't contain zero.

Comment: What is one such example that doesn't contain zero?

Comment: The OP is (I believe) asking whether there is a branch of mathematics that can help with reasoning about issues such as undefined terms. Mathematical logic is the place to start.

Comment: @ Greg. Paul, according to the law of indices:   1 = 1, so, 1 ^2 = 1^3, hence 2 = 3

Comment: @bzal But the law of indices works essentially because, in many circumstances, $f(x) = b^x$ is an invertible function. This is clearly not the case when $b = 1$.

Comment: @pjs36, I might have come late but here's another:       ((-2)^1/2)^2 = 2,     (((i^2) X 2) ^ (1/2) = 2,       (i((2)^(1/2))^2 = 2 , which implies -2 = 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The branch of mathematics known as [mathematical logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_logic) deals very carefully with what you describe as flaws.

Comment: I'm not sure that's a good characterization of mathematical logic; that's not really the right tool to use to look at flawed arithmetic, where one really just needs to look more closely at relevant axioms.

Comment: Duh? I didn't offer a characterization of mathematical logic. However mathematical logic is the subject that forces you to look at axioms.